# After deleting my github fork with an accidental commit and forking afresh, the accidental commit is still there

Tags: git, github

1. I forked some public github repo
2. then in a different private github project directory, I `--set-upstream` to that public fork
3. pushed that private branch to the public fork

I had intended to do 2. and 3. in my public fork, but I accidentally ran those commands in the wrong GNU screen tab, which is why the branch of a private project ended up being published.

As soon as I realized what had happened, I "permanently" (that most dangerous of github admin operations which github states cannot be undone) deleted my github fork, and just forked again, thinking all was dandy now.

Later I was made aware by the owner of the private repo, that their private code was on my public fork. They gave me a URL `https://github.com/<MY-ACCOUNT>/<PROJECT-NAME>/tree/<SHA1>`, and I could indeed access it using that URL.

So how can I get rid of this private branch on my public fork? I tried to

- `git push origin --delete <SHA1>`
- `git checkout <SHA1>`
- `git revert <SHA1>`
- enter  in the public fork's branch change combo box on `https://github.com/<MY-ACCOUNT>/<PROJECT-NAME>`

neither of which worked, the cmd line attempts failing with something like this:

```sh
$ git push origin --delete <SHA1>
error: unable to delete '<SHA1>': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:<MY-ACCOUNT>/<PROJECT-NAME>.git'
```

So it seems the branch is still accessible, but it can neither be checked out nor can it be deleted. Retrying to permanently delete the branch and re-fork did not help either.

Thinking, it just needs GCing, I also tried to

```sh
git gc --prune=now
git push -f --all
```

which did not remove the unwanted branch.

**So how can I work on that public fork, without the private branch being in it?**

Comment: And you couldn't just create a branch on the fork because... ?

Comment: @marblewraith I need to delete a branch - not create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I filed a request with github.com, and what they did was clear their cache of the repository, which seems to have done the trick! So when I forked once more, the private branch was gone.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Saved me. I had the same problem and was going crazy with the issue. I contacted GitHub support through their ticket system and asked them to clear the views cache of the repo, and that fixed it!