# Git pushes unrelated commits from another project in a different folder to my repo in github

Tags: git, github

I have a problem I cannot seem to understand nor fix. I have a project from the place I work for placed in `myUser/Documents/Projects/work_project` and I have created a fork from a repo on my personal github account.

I have another folder in `myUser/Documents/Forks/myFork` and I have made some changes to that repo locally and commited them there. After that, I push them to my remote fork, to later submit the new banch as a PR to the original repo. The thing is, as soon as I push these new changes on the fork, I get a warning from AWS telling me I have submitted some private files publically from my `work_project` in a commit (and it gives me the URL from the commit in the github fork, and there they are). The commit does not belong to any branch from the fork, but they are still there (it says commit does not belong to any branch).

I have no idea what is happening, or what am I doing wrong. I have checked me `/Documents` (and `/myUser` too) for a `.git` file that is maybe tracking unwanted stuff on both projects with `ls -a` but I couldn't find anything. It's super weird. Once I see the public commit with private files, I delete the repo (fork) to avoid any problems. Later I fork again from the original repo, and the commit with the private files are already there! Even though i have deleted the repo and re-forked it, it seems it "somehow" saves the commits from the last time i forked-push changes to the fork? I am really lost here.

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure you have your remotes set up properly? Are you sure you've been committing to the correct fork of your repo?

Comment: @DanielMann The remote (origin) of the repo I'm pulling and pushing from is set up properly (I have tried multiple times), and yes I have been comitting to the correct fork of the repo (My work_project is from gitlab actually, and the fork I'm pushing to is on github). My best guess is it's some weird git config I can't seem to find or fix.

Comment: You can investigate what is going on by taking the SHA hash shown for the problematic commit. In each of your local repos, do `git log <commit-hash>` to see more information about that particular commit. What is the output of this command when you run it in `work_project`? What about in `myFork`?

Comment: On a side note, if these private files have any sensitive information, that information is compromised once it is in a public repo, even if you delete the repo somewhat quickly. You need to assess any security concerns and deal with them quickly.

Answer (score 0):

For future references, I found the solution to my problem in this thread [After deleting my github fork with an accidental commit and forking afresh, the accidental commit is still there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59793930/after-deleting-my-github-fork-with-an-accidental-commit-and-forking-afresh-the) . He had the same issue as I did. Solution was contacting Github support through their tickets system and asking them to clear their cached views of the original repo I forked from. That seemed to have cleared the problem!